# Navigating JSON with jQuery results in undefined items

Tags: jquery, json

I want to loop through some data which is in JSON.

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "1561",
        "companyName": "Keeley Furniture Limited",
        "lat": "51.50622110",
        "lng": "-0.10131790",
        "city": "London",
        "street1": "123 Waldorf St",
        "street2": null,
        "street3": "",
        "zip": "SE1 0SW",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "email": "aamir@dwelldf.co.uk",
        "profile": "http:\/\/craft.fira\/directory\/company\/1561\/keeley-furniture-limited",
        "businessCategories": []
    }, {
        "id": "1501", ...etc
```

So far I have this:

```
$(function() {
     var $members = $('#memberlist');

     $.getJSON("/directory/JSON/fullmembers.json", function(memberlist) {
         console.log('success');
         var members = memberlist.data;
         $.each(members, function(member) {
             $members.append("<li>" + member["companyName"] + "</li>");
         });
    });
});
```

Which just results in lots of `<li>undefined</li>` being appended to the ul. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in the `each()` handler function is the index of the current element in the array. The element itself is the second parameter. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("/directory/JSON/fullmembers.json", function(memberlist) {
     console.log('success');
     var members = memberlist.data;
     $.each(members, function(index, member) { // note the 'index' param here
         $members.append("<li>" + member["companyName"] + "</li>");
     });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bdeL4z18/)

Comment: That did it Rory, thank you so much! I'll mark as correct when I can. Much appreciated. Have a great day :-)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.